# Can't get RCaller to to run simple example

Tags: java, r, rcaller

I am trying to run this simple example of RCaller on my windows 7 machine.

```
        RCaller caller = new RCaller();
        RCode code = new RCode();
        caller.setRscriptExecutable("C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.2.1\\bin\\Rscript.exe");
        double[] numbers = new double[]{1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 10};
        code.addDoubleArray("x", numbers);
        code.addRCode("my.mean<-mean(x)");
        code.addRCode("my.var<-var(x)");
        code.addRCode("my.all<-list(mean=my.mean, variance=my.var)");
        caller.setRCode(code);
        caller.runAndReturnResult("my.all");
        double[] results = caller.getParser().getAsDoubleArray("mean");`
        System.out.println(results[0]);
```

This is the error message:

```
   cat(makexml(obj=my.all, name="my.all"), file="C:/Users/Bob Smith/AppData/Local/Temp/Routput8089051805366000971")

   rcaller.exception.ParseException: Can not handle R results due to :    rcaller.exception.ParseException: Can not parse output: The generated file C:\Users\Bob Smith\AppData\Local\Temp\Routput8089051805366000971 is empty
```

I've tried several versions of RCaller (this example is 2.2.0) and have received similar errors. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I just tried your code and it works, try the new `RCaller` version http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.jbytecode/RCaller/2.8